# Moving Transaction Logic to Middle Layer: Pros and Cons

Tags: architecture, aws, transaction, middleware

We have an event booking system that allows patrons to add themselves to a waiting list if an event is fully booked. When somebody cancels, the system moves the first person from the waitlist into a booked status. Currently, this is implemented as a stored procedure that locks the table to avoid someone slipping out of order. However, the business logic that checks event eligibility and promotion rules has grown complicated, and the stored procedure is challenging to maintain and test.

I am considering moving all the logic into the middle layer, but this would mean that the lock would need to be implemented outside of the database. Is this a bad idea? I think having a special worker that processes all booking requests would be a simpler solution that scales better as the number of events and patrons grows.

If I go this route, what managed services in AWS should I look at?

Thanks!

Comment: Why locking at all? The waiting list processor should be treated like any other entity booking a place in an event. What's the race condition against which your lock should protect?

Comment: Oh and I removed the message-queue tag as it doesn't seem related to the question.

Comment: Is any other (foreign) process altering the table? Any other app,  service, system, or batch process? Can we assume that the procedure is being triggered by a DB event like an insert or update?

Comment: Yes, in addition to patrons scheduling and cancelling events, which are concurrent requests by itself, there is an admin interface for event organizers where they can update attendees at will or change event capacity.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner I suppose the point is that no actual user can get the booking during the time between the space becoming available and the waiting-list user booking it

Comment: @user253751 If everything goes right, yes, it is impossible. But if for whatever reason second transaction (wait list promotion) fails or gets aborted, there is plenty of opportunities for somebody to sign up out of order. You run it long enough, and it will happen.
Why implement a system with know race condition when it is possible to avoid it?

Comment: @Anatol5 do admin changes prevail over those coming from requests? In the case of concurrency or a match between a request and admin changes, which one should win? The first to arrive? The admin? Is there any problem with rejecting changes or requests?

Comment: what is the middle layer?

Comment: No problem with retrying changes either from client or admin as long as DB stays in a consistent state.
The current system is ASP.NET/MS SQL, but I will reimplement it. This is why I am asking. Whatever is easier to integrate with cloud managed solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mention of a stored procedure suggests to me that you are working with a relational (sql) database.

You don't need anything more fancy than a simple database transaction over the cancellation/waitlist logic. The process of freeing up a space due to a cancellation and immediately filling that space with the first eligible person on the waitlist should be performed withing a single transaction.

By using a transaction, you will not have any risk that someone registering anew will jump the queue and take the place of someone on the waitlist, because the temporarily free spot will not be visible until the transaction has been committed and that spot been occupied by someone from the waitlist.

There is a race condition with two cancellations happening at the same time and picking the same person from the waitlist. If your database is well-designed for this possibility, it will fail one of the transactions<sup>1</sup>. The failed transaction can then be just retried.

There is a really small chance of a race condition if an event is fully booked, but there are no persons on the waitlist and both a new registration and a cancellation arrive at the same time. Then the situation can occur that the new registration is put on the waitlist, while also a space is freed up. This can be resolved by periodically checking if there is both free space and a waitlist and to admit people from the waitlist in that case.

---

<sup>1: It might interest you. [Concurrency Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_control)</sup>

Comment: Yes, this is the current implementation and it works. The problem is that there are relatively complicated business rules that govern event eligibility, timing of cancellations and registrations, etc. Those rules are changing periodically and maintaining them in SQL in addition to middle layer is quite a pain. And they have to be in the middle layer for display purposes.

Comment: @Anatol5, using transactions does not mean that all code running within the transaction needs to be written in SQL or in a stored procedure. It is very common to initiate a transaction from application code, perform various calculations in <your preferred language> to determine the values to fill into the SQL queries and then commit the transaction from application code. This involves multiple requests to the database.

Comment: if you do this you should be aware that if two threads try to do conflicting things at the same time, one transaction will *fail* and you just try it again. (E.g. you open a slot and then pick someone off the waitlist and give them the slot, but the person already came off the waitlist at the same time by coincidence. The transaction fails and you do the same thing again except a different person is picked because the first one isn't still in the waitlist. You need to test this to make sure the transaction does fail)

Comment: Well, you almost convinced me that moving some of the business logic out of stored procs and guarding from most probable race conditions with a DB transaction is the way to go. I will probably do just that.
The idea behind the question though, was to have a message queue and dedicated singular processing node to handle event registrations. It adds complexity, but the good thing is, there is no concurrency at all. Then to scale it, I can assign different events to different processing nodes if needed.